# Renamed files in Xcode, now cannot commit without deselecting files

Tags: ios, xcode, git, commit, renaming

In my project I have a UITableViewController subclass with files named "someTableViewController.h" and "someTableViewController.m" On a whim I decided to rename them to "SomeTableViewController.h" and "SomeTableViewController.m", but after a short moment I decided the previous look was better and I changed their names back to the originals.

However, now whenever I try to commit, Xcode will throw an error saying "error: pathspec 'Project/SomeTableViewController.h' did not match any file(s) known to git" and "error: pathspec 'Project/SomeTableViewController.m' did not match any file(s) known to git". It seems that Xcode keeps thinking the outdated names for the files still exist and refuse to acknowledge them being changed.

The only way I could get around it is by manually deselecting these two files in the commit window before committing, but I don't want to have to do that every time I commit because I anticipate this project easily reaching at least a hundred commits. Is there any way to fix this issue without adding a .gitignore file?